# AWS.Cryptography.EncryptionSDK.AwsEncryptionSdkException: Failed to build header body

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, aws-sdk, amazon-kms

I'm trying to use the AWS Encryption SDK for .NET to encrypt and decrypt plain text using KMS. When encrypting a string I see the the error in the title. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as I'm basically following the [example code provided by AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/dot-net.html#net-kms-keyrings) save for specifying credentials such that the SDK can access the KMS key (if I don't sepcify credentials I get the follwoing error 'Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException: Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service.'). I've already checked that the AccessKeyId and SecretKey have full access to the KMS key that is being specified using _options.KmsKeyArn. The error message isn't helpful at all. The same error is thrown when I attempt to use SessionCredentials with a token that hasn't expired yet.

`

```
public class CryptographyService : ICryptographyService
{

    private readonly ESDK _cryptoClient;
    private readonly MaterialProviders _materialProviders;
    private readonly CryptographyOptions _options;
    private readonly IKeyring _keyRing;

    public CryptographyService(IOptions<CryptographyOptions> options)
    {
        _options = options.Value;

        var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(_options.AccessKey, _options.SecretKey);

        _cryptoClient = new ESDK(new AwsEncryptionSdkConfig());
        _materialProviders = new MaterialProviders(new MaterialProvidersConfig());

        var keyringInput = new CreateAwsKmsKeyringInput
        {
            KmsClient = new AmazonKeyManagementServiceClient(credentials, RegionEndpoint.GetBySystemName(_options.RegionEndpoint)),
            KmsKeyId = _options.KmsKeyArn
        };

        _keyRing = _materialProviders.CreateAwsKmsKeyring(keyringInput);

        var createCmmInput = new CreateRequiredEncryptionContextCMMInput
        {
            UnderlyingCMM = _materialProviders.CreateDefaultCryptographicMaterialsManager(new CreateDefaultCryptographicMaterialsManagerInput { Keyring = _keyRing }),
            RequiredEncryptionContextKeys = new List<string>(_options.GetEncryptionContext().Keys)
        };

        _ = _materialProviders.CreateRequiredEncryptionContextCMM(createCmmInput);
    }

    public async ValueTask<string> EncryptPlainText(string plainText)
    {
        EncryptOutput encryptOutput;
        await using (var stream = MemoryStreamFromString(plainText))
        {
            var encryptInput = new EncryptInput()
            {
                Plaintext = stream,
                Keyring = _keyRing,
                EncryptionContext = _options.GetEncryptionContext()
            };
            encryptOutput = _cryptoClient.Encrypt(encryptInput);
        }
        return StringFromMemoryStream(encryptOutput.Ciphertext);
    }

    private static MemoryStream MemoryStreamFromString(string s) => new(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(s));
}`
```

I tried using session credentials with a valid token, specifying an encryption algorithm, not using an encryption context, not speciyfing CMM. All of this leads to the same error message. Not specifying credentials leads to an error message 'Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException: Unable to get IAM security credentials from EC2 Instance Metadata Service.'

Comment: Version 3 or 4 of the .net SDK? Is the KMS key symmetrical or asymmetrical? Have you tried using a different language (C, Java, Dart) to confirm this key and creds work?

Comment: Can you replace all of this code with a simple 'list objects in S3 bucket' to ensure your credentials work? If that throws the error or doesn't, let us know. How are you getting these credentials?

Comment: @RichardHeap version 4 of the SDK. I think I might try to build a quick Python bot to test whether it works from there. The KMS key is symmetrical and I made sure it can be used for both encryption and decryption.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I just generated credentials (AccessKeyId and SecretKey) for a user with full access to KMS and added the relevant HSM permissions to the policy too. I'm first going to build the bot above and then try the S3 List.

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary I created a KM client and did a list keys call and all the keys are available in the debugger.

Comment: If you look at the source code of the library, you see that it is getting past getting the key and fails in generating the header for the ciphertext. You might want to try running it in a dafny debugger to see why it fails.

Comment: Update: I got the Python version of the code to work and it successfully encrypted and decrypted the plan text I provided. I used the same credentials as I've been using in the .Net project.